# How can I remove 'Dark Mode' from Ms Office apps without disabling it across macOS?

Tags: macos, ms-office, mojave, dark-mode

I am running macOS Mojave and have Dark Mode set as my default appearance in Apple > System Preferences > General.

I recently updated MS Office on my Mac and the latest MS Office update (i.e. version 16.20) supports Dark Mode. However, unlike many other apps, there is no way to enable/disable this appearance within the app itself.

Since I much prefer the usual appearance of my MS Office apps, but still want to use Dark Mode within macOS, how can I achieve this outcome?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To disable Dark Mode for MS Office only, you need to run a terminal command for each of the MS Office apps in question.

For example, if you wish to disable dark mode in MS Excel, follow these steps:

1. Quit Excel if it’s running
2. Launch Terminal (usually found in the Applications/Utilities folder)
3. Enter (or copy and paste) the following command: `defaults write com.microsoft.Excel NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool yes`
4. Now press <kbd>return</kbd>
5. Enter (or copy and paste) the following command:  `killall cfprefsd`
6. Now press <kbd>return</kbd>

Now when you launch MS Excel it should appear as it it normally would without Dark Mode enabled.

**NOTES:**

- To do this with the other MS Office apps, just change the command at Step 3 so that it’s referencing the app in question.
- Each of the app names within the command must start with an uppercase letter (note the uppercase 'E' for Excel in the command at Step 3.
- For PowerPoint, the app name must be spelt as follows: `Powerpoint` (i.e. only the first P is in uppercase, not both Ps)
- To revert back to Dark Mode, follow the same steps but end the command at Step 3 with `no` instead of `yes`.

Comment: I recently learned about a Menu bar app called [NightOwl](http://nightowl.kramser.xyz) which gives a toggle to switch between dark and light mode. Interestingly it also offers the ability to toggle the mode on a per app basis. I think it's making use of something similar as described in your post to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to use an app called [lights off](https://www.lightsoff-app.com) or [Night Owl.](https://nightowl.kramser.xyz/)
These both provide the option to turn off dark mode for specific apps:

> With LightsOff you can easily and quickly switch between light and dark mode and even specify what mode you want on a per app basis.

This provides a checkbox interface where you toggle modes in all apps:

[image]